# How to select last element of a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = open("unknown.txt", 'r')
a = sum(line.count('ly') for line in f)

f = open("unknown.txt", 'r')
words = 0

for line in f:
    words += len(line.split())
    print(words)
```

So this code outputs numbers leading up to 78, which is the amount of words in the text file, how do I get '78' and only '78'? So I can use it by itself, thanks in advance!

Comment: You *have* `78` in the variable `words`?

Comment: Try moving the print call out of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in f:
    words += len(line.split())
    print(words)
```

This prints the total number of words after every line in the file. If you only want to print the amount of words after python has calculated how many there are, de-indent your `print` call:

```
for line in f:
    words += len(line.split())

print(words)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to count the number of words in a file.

The best way to do that is using the built-in `len` function.

```
with open(file_path) as f:
    words = len(f.read().split())
```

---

To deal with larger files, you should do it through iteration (a generator), here is a function:

```
def words_in_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        return sum(len(line.split()) for line in f)
```

Using the function:

```
>>> words_in_file('C:/Python27/README.txt')
7491
```

Comment: Note that this will potentially run into problems with really large files, as it has to read it all into memory. It might be better to add up line-by-line in that (admittedly rare) case.

Comment: @Lattyware too true - edited to reflect.